# AutoFixture Register type globally

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture in this instance to materialize objects containing a Mongo ObjectId, like so

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Register(ObjectId.GenerateNewId);
```

But I am doing this for every test.  Is it possible to register this globall somehow for all tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this *globally* (or *statically*).

What I usually do is create a `TestConventions` class that contains all the customizations I want to apply to every test.

```
internal class TestConventions : CompositeCustomization
{
    public TestConventions() :
        base(
            new MongoObjectIdCustomization())
    {

    }

    private class MongoObjectIdCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Register(ObjectId.GenerateNewId);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I apply these conventions to every test:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions());
```

If you're using the AutoFixture.XUnit2 (or AutoFixture.NUnit) plugin, you can reduce this boilerplate by defining an attribute that imports your test conventions:

```
public class MyProjectAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public MyProjectAutoDataAttribute() : base(
        new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions()))
    {

    }
}
```

And then apply it to your test cases:

```
[Theory, MyProjectAutoData]
public void SomeFact(SomeClass sut)
{

}
```

Comment: This is great, but considering I have a class `Message` I'd like to auto fill the rest of the fields, what do we do now? Normally I would use the InlineAutoData attribute, and then leave an additional (.... Message message) hanging in the test parameters.

Comment: I was able to create all of these classes then add the attribute to the test, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I created a convention class as suggested by @drcastro but I ended up creating a TestBase class which I inherit from in my Unit test class

```
  public class TestBase
    {
        public IFixture GenerateNewFixture()
        {
            return new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFixtureConventions());
        }
    }

 internal class AutoFixtureConventions : CompositeCustomization
    {
        public AutoFixtureConventions() :
            base(
                new MongoObjectIdCustomization())
        {

        }

        private class MongoObjectIdCustomization : ICustomization
        {
            public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
            {
                fixture.Register(ObjectId.GenerateNewId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this

```
    public class FixtureWithFoo: Fixture
    {
        public FixtureWithFoo()
        {
            Customizations.Add(new FooCustomization()); 
            //Or register something else
        }
    }
```

and then use it in your test

```
var fixture = new FixtureWithFoo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by registering an ISpecimenBuilder as I needed to match on some criteria concerning PropertyInfo.

```
private class MongoObjectIdSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            if (request is PropertyInfo info
                && info.PropertyType == typeof(ObjectId)
                && ...)
                return ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }
    }

// register the builder
AutoFixture.Customizations.Add(new MongoObjectIdSpecimenBuilder());
```

Comment: Thanks but you should remove the ToString. MongoDB object ID is not a string type. This will throw an error at the runtime.